# how to embed Pdf and Video Without effecting page speed?

Tags: performance

I have a WordPress site and I upload a lot of pdf and videos use embedding techniques but now my website speed is very low. so i want to increase the page speed now, I am going to delete all the iframe from my website and want to replace them with responsive iframe, but I don't know how to use embedding. currently, i embedded all pdf using google drive embedding.
**should I stop embedding??**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to load PDFs & videos on your page after the page is completely loaded via AJAX. You can also use a logic in which only after the page loads completely, load the PDFs & videos on mouse move and while the page loading is in progress show a loader in place of PDFs & videos.

I have used this technique at many places and it works like a charm. Hope this helps you.

Comment: can you suggest me how to do it in my wordpress i need to install plugin or any script can guide me

Comment: @FahadsmileAcademyPakistan You would need to code it in PHP and JS.